# 2000+ processor wake ups..?

Tags: 11.10, backup, battery, cpu-load, nvidia-optimus

I have dell xps 15 with nvidia 525 with optimus. I use ironhide for optimus support. Under normal conditions I can see 2000+ processor wake ups. As a result of which my battery dries up rapidly. In windows I get almost 4 hours back up and in ubuntu I hardly get 2+ hours battery backup. I'm not able to identify what the problem is. I'm using ubuntu 11.10 32-bit. Please help to resolve my issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can check what processes are responsible for wake ups using `gnome-power-statistics`..

There is also a tool called `powertop` which might be of help.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerTOP

http://www.linuxpowertop.org/

http://www.lesswatts.org/projects/powertop/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a side-effect of using Ironhide' power management method using ACPI calls (which does not make the kernel aware of device state changes). Bumblebee 3.0 provides more stable power management using bbswitch.

Upgrade from Ironhide to Bumblebee 3.0 following the instructions on http://wiki.Bumblebee-Project.org/Upgrading-on-Ubuntu

See also: [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969)